# XML to Linq to classes

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Using the code metrics power tool I started saving some of my code metrics to a xml file. What I want to do is to take said file drill down to each Member and grab its metrics. The code I have right now gets all the Members correctly, but what I can't figure out is how to get the Metrics.

Each Member will have 4 metrics always. a simple example from one of the outputs would be this

```
<Members>
  <Member Name="GetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid, out int, out int) : long">
     <Metrics>
        <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="100" />
        <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="1" />
        <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="1" />
        <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="0" />
     </Metrics>
  </Member>
  <Member Name="SetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid, int, int) : long">
     <Metrics>
        <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="100" />
        <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="1" />
        <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="1" />
        <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="0" />
     </Metrics>
  </Member>
</Members>
```

Here is the class that I defined to save the name of the member and the metric results

```
public class CodeMetricResult
{
    public CodeMetric Metric { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}[{1}]", Name, Metric);
    }
}
```

and here is CodeMetric

```
public class CodeMetric
{
    public int LinesOfCode { get; set; }

    public int MaintainabilityIndex { get; set; }

    public int CyclomaticComplexity { get; set; }

    public int ClassCoupling { get; set; }

    public int DepthOfInheritance { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Metrics: Maintainability:{0} Complexity:{1} Coupling:{2} Lines:{3}", MaintainabilityIndex, CyclomaticComplexity, ClassCoupling, LinesOfCode);
    }
}
```

here is my method that I am starting to build to parse the xml file

```
public static class CodeMetricFileReader
{
    public static IEnumerable<CodeMetricResult> ReadFile(string fileName)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);

        var mySteps = (from s in doc.Descendants("Member")
                       select new CodeMetricResult()
                       {
                           Name = s.Attribute("Name").Value,
                           Metric = new CodeMetric()
                           {
                                //but what do I put here?
                           },
                       });

        return mySteps;
    }
}
```

I've only written a handful of LINQ statements before and yesterday is when it clicked... but this is still over my head a little bit. So how do I make the second part of the equation? to help with any tests you may do on your end here is the structure of the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeMetricsReport Version="11">
   <Targets>
      <Target Name="C:\SomeLocation\Foobar.dll">
         <Modules>
            <Module Name="Foobar.dll" AssemblyVersion="1.0.0.0" FileVersion="1.0.0.0">
               <Metrics>
                  <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="95" />
                  <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="32" />
                  <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="14" />
                  <Metric Name="DepthOfInheritance" Value="2" />
                  <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="34" />
               </Metrics>
               <Namespaces>
                  <Namespace Name="FooBarActiveX">
                     <Metrics>
                        ...
                     </Metrics>
                     <Types>
                        <Type Name="ObjectSafetyOptions">
                           <Metrics>
                                ...
                           </Metrics>
                           <Members />
                        </Type>
                        <Type Name="IObjectSafety">
                           <Metrics>
                                ...
                           </Metrics>
                           <Members>
                              <Member Name="GetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid, out int, out int) : long">
                                 <Metrics>
                                    ...
                                 </Metrics>
                              </Member>
                              <Member Name="SetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid, int, int) : long">
                                 <Metrics>
                                    ...
                                 </Metrics>
                              </Member>
                              <Member>
                                ...
                              </Member>
                           </Members>
                        </Type>
                        <Type>
                            ...
                        </Type>
                     </Types>
                  </Namespace>
                  <Namespace>
                    ...
                  </Namespace>
               </Namespaces>
            </Module>
         </Modules>
      </Target>
      <Target ...>
            ...
      </Target>
   </Targets>
</CodeMetricsReport>
```

and as a bonus.. how does one TDD this sorta stuff? cause I wrote a test.. then realized.. oh this isn't very testable.. and the test I wrote is evident of that. Any thoughts on how to TDD this sorta thing? Here is my lame smelly test

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestXmlDeSerialization()
    {
        var results = CodeMetricFileReader.ReadFile("CodeMetricSaveFiles\\test.xml");
        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

well i got it to work... it feels like a hack to me.. but it works.

```
    public static IEnumerable<CodeMetricResult> ReadFile(string fileName)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);

        var mySteps = (from s in doc.Descendants("Member")
                       select new CodeMetricResult()
                       {
                           Name = s.Attribute("Name").Value,
                           Metric = ParseMetrics(s.Element("Metrics").Elements("Metric")),
                       });

        return mySteps;
    }

    private static CodeMetric ParseMetrics(IEnumerable<XElement> nodes)
    {
        var metric = new CodeMetric();
        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
            int value = int.Parse(node.Attribute("Value").Value);
            switch (node.Attribute("Name").Value)
            {
                case "MaintainabilityIndex":
                    metric.MaintainabilityIndex = value;
                    break;

                case "CyclomaticComplexity":
                    metric.CyclomaticComplexity = value;
                    break;

                case "ClassCoupling":
                    metric.ClassCoupling = value;
                    break;

                case "LinesOfCode":
                    metric.LinesOfCode = value;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return metric;
    }
```

**Edit2**

well after much pondering I realized that I don't need the member name. All i really am after is just the numbers each "Member". which I built up and I think the code worked out rather well.

```
public static class CodeMetricFileReader
{
    public static IEnumerable<CodeMetric> ReadFile(string fileName)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);

        var mySteps = (from s in doc.Descendants("Member")
                       select ParseMetrics(s.Element("Metrics").Elements("Metric"))
                       );

        return mySteps;
    }

    private static CodeMetric ParseMetrics(IEnumerable<XElement> nodes)
    {
        var metric = new CodeMetric();
        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
            int value = int.Parse(node.Attribute("Value").Value);
            switch (node.Attribute("Name").Value)
            {
                case "MaintainabilityIndex":
                    metric.MaintainabilityIndex = value;
                    break;

                case "CyclomaticComplexity":
                    metric.CyclomaticComplexity = value;
                    break;

                case "ClassCoupling":
                    metric.ClassCoupling = value;
                    break;

                case "LinesOfCode":
                    metric.LinesOfCode = value;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return metric;
    }
}
```

which then I made a CodeMetricMathClass

```
public static class CodeMetricMath
{
    public static CodeMetricStatistics GenerateStatistics(this IEnumerable<CodeMetric> metrics)
    {
        int linesOfCode = metrics.Sum(x => x.LinesOfCode);
        var maintenance = ExtractStatistic(metrics, x => x.MaintainabilityIndex);
        var complexity = ExtractStatistic(metrics, x => x.CyclomaticComplexity);
        var coupling = ExtractStatistic(metrics, x => x.ClassCoupling);
        return new CodeMetricStatistics(maintenance, complexity, coupling, linesOfCode);
    }

    private static Statistic ExtractStatistic(IEnumerable<CodeMetric> metrics, Func<CodeMetric, int> func)
    {
        IEnumerable<int> numbers = metrics.Select(func);
        double max = numbers.Max();
        double min = numbers.Min();
        double avg = numbers.Average();
        double stdDev = numbers.StandardDeviation();
        var stat = new Statistic(max, min, avg + stdDev, avg - stdDev);
        return stat;
    }

    public static double StandardDeviation(this IEnumerable<int> numbers)
    {
        double average = numbers.Average();
        double deviationAverage = numbers.Average(x => Math.Pow(x - average, 2));

        return Math.Sqrt(deviationAverage);
    }
}
```

and with a nice little test to back it up

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestXmlSerialization()
    {
        var results = CodeMetricFileReader.ReadFile("CodeMetricSaveFiles\\test.xml");
        var statistics = results.GenerateStatistics();
        Assert.AreEqual(824, statistics.LinesOfCode);
        AssertThat.StatisticsAreEqual(100, 42, 98.15288705, 68.65499472, statistics.MaintainabilityStatistic);
        AssertThat.StatisticsAreEqual(18, 1, 4.126452095, -0.451575247, statistics.ComplexityStatistic);
        AssertThat.StatisticsAreEqual(12, 0, 4.999814386, 0.16274719, statistics.ClassCouplingStatistic);
    }

public static class AssertThat
{
    public static void StatisticsAreEqual(double expectedMax, double expectedMin, double expectedHigh, double expectedLow, Statistic actualStatistic)
    {
        double difference = 0.0000001;
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedMax, actualStatistic.Max, difference, string.Format("Expected Max has a difference of {0}", expectedMax - actualStatistic.Max));
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedMin, actualStatistic.Min, difference, string.Format("Expected Min has a difference of {0}", expectedMin - actualStatistic.Min));
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedHigh, actualStatistic.HighAverage, difference, string.Format("Expected HighAverage has a difference of {0}", expectedHigh - actualStatistic.HighAverage));
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedLow, actualStatistic.LowAverage, difference, string.Format("Expected LowAverage has a difference of {0}", expectedLow - actualStatistic.LowAverage));
    }
}
```

and just in case you were wondering what my output is...

```
MaintainabilityIndex:[Max:100.0 High:101.0 Low:77.9 Min:56.0]
CyclomaticComplexity:[Max:9.0 High:3.0 Low:-0.1 Min:1.0]
ClassCoupling:[Max:8.0 High:3.6 Low:-0.8 Min:0.0]
Lines of Code: 111
```

Comment: In your edit, you indicate that you found a solution to your question. When that happens, you should [really post your own answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/12519/243253).

Comment: @DavidRR normally I do, but my excuse is 2 fold. 1 is that I feel like I have an outstanding question that I would like to see answered. and 2 I think i'm still in the "You have to wait x many hours to answer your own question", but i'll double check that second part.

Comment: By reading this entire thing it is not clear, what your remaining question actually is.